# Refresh Page Edge

Tags: javascript, php, browser, refresh, page-refresh

The code I have works in chrome, operates and firefox correctly but in Internet Edge it does not work at 100%.
When I use the code to refresh the page in Chrome for example, the page gives refresh and stays where it was. In Internet Edge when page gives refresh back to the beginning of the same, that is, everything up.

Code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 
        'window.location.reload(true);',
        '</script>';
```

Comment: Yeahh...IE is the pain in the a** for many developers.

Comment: Yeah... So we don´t have a solution for this problem?